# LAST_INSERT_ID , не получается вставить в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь в titles_id Title_info добавить  LAST_INSERT_ID   и не получается.В другие таблицы добавляется спокойно да и в саму  Title_info добавляется, если добавлять все поля. Полагаю, что все из-за foreign key, но не знаю, как исправить и возможно ли?

```
InsertRow("INSERT INTO Titles (title, duration_from, duration_to) VALUES (?,?,?);
INSERT INTO Title_info(titles_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID());",["Gatari","3","4"]);
```

Title info
[image: Таблица Title_info]

[image: Таблица Title_info]

Titles

[image: Таблица Titles]

UPD:скриншот связей Title_info
[image: Title_info]

Используемая функция для insert

```
public function insertRow( $query,$params = [] ) {
        try {
            $stmt = $this->datab->prepare($query);
            $stmt->execute($params);
             return TRUE;
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo __LINE__.$e->getMessage();
        }
```

Comment: 1) `INSERT INTO Title_info(titles_id) SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` 2) А `$stmt->execute($params);` разве поддерживает мультизапросы?

Comment: @Akina, это функция моего класса, только что добавил. И что вы имеете в виду  здесь "1) INSERT INTO Title_info(titles_id) SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();"?

Comment: *что вы имеете в виду здесь* То, что лишняя обёртка в запросе не нужна.

Comment: @Akina На счет поддержки мультизапросов не знаю, скорее всего нет и лучше bindParam,но в данном случае вряд ли это влияет.По крайней мере с другие таблицы записывает, а в главную нет.

Comment: *На счет поддержки мультизапросов не знаю, скорее всего нет* А у Вас как раз мультизапрос...

Comment: @ Akina Но ведь в другие таблицы все добавляется, кроме Table_info.

Comment: У вас в tile_info я вижу аж 7 полей not null. почему вы при вставке записи заполняете только поле titles_id ? Надо заполнить все поля

Comment: Я это знаю, вопрос скорее в том, как заполнить такую таблицу? Сейчас на полях без внешнего ключа поставил null, но 5 полей с внешним ключом нужно как-то заполнить. Разве что сначала заполнить другие таблицы, а потом из них взять значения и передать в главную?

Comment: Конечно. Сначала основные таблицы, потом подчиненную. Иначе зачем нужна запись со ссылками, которая ни на что не ссылается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему в таблице `Title_info` есть столбцы не имеющие значений по умолчанию и `not null` при этом. В таком случае вставка завершится с ошибкой. Проверьте ошибки при выполнении запроса вставки. Попробуйте просто сделать такой запрос в phpMyAdmin'е, заменив `LAST_INSERT_ID()` на  id произвольного `Titles`.

Comment: Менял значения по умолчанию и толку нет. При попытке сделать запрос выдает.Все же дело во внешнем ключе, но как это можно исправить?  Error number: 1452; Symbol: ER_NO_REFERENCED_ROW_2; SQLSTATE: 23000

Message: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (%s)

InnoDB reports this error when you try to add a row but there is no parent row, and a foreign key constraint fails. Add the parent row first.

Comment: Так создайте парента ( строку в таблице `Titles`), посмотрите какой у него id и попробуйте с ним.

Comment: Никак. В   Title_info  добавляются только сразу все 5 параметров, которые имеют внешний ключ, что логично, либо не добавляются вовсе.Что-то в данном случае можно сделать  или  только добавлять все сразу?

Comment: Все, я уже понял. Foreign key как раз и проверяет существуют ли такие элементы в связанной таблице и, соответственно, пустым или нулевым поле с ключом быть не может.Спасибо. Хотя можно вам ещё вопрос задать? Как тогда заполнять такую таблицу? Все сразу одним запросом что ли?

Comment: *Foreign key как раз и проверяет существуют ли такие элементы в связанной таблице и, соответственно, пустым или нулевым поле с ключом быть не может.* Насчёт NULL Вы неправы - тут срабатывает ограничение поля, а не внешнего ключа, которому, если описатель поля допускает, чхать на NULL.

Comment: *Все сразу одним запросом что ли?* INSERT не поддерживает добавление в несколько таблиц. Впрочем, в версии 8+ допускается выполнять добавление в секции WITH, что может быть решением. Но и там - сперва добавляют в таблицу на стороне "один", и только потом - на стороне "много".

Comment: Спасибо, я понял.Но как тогда можно заполнить таблицу, в которой 5 внешних ключей? Разве что сначала заполнить другие таблицы, а потом из них взять значения и передать в главную?

Comment: @Алексей именно так.